# Как правильно поставить constraint

Tags: xcode, swift, autolayout, constraints

Задача такая, что синий label должен растягиваться до середины клетки в зависимости от длины текста (стоит label trailing <= cell.center.x). Это работает корректно. Теперь мне нужно, чтобы красный label растягивался до того момента, пока расстояние между синим и красным не превышает 1 (ну или любое другое число). Я ставлю у красного лэйбла redLabel.leading >=1 blueLabel.trailing. Все работает нормально, только вот синий лэйбл у меня главный, то есть он должен растягиваться только по своим ограничениям, а красный, в случае если оба лэйбла длинные, должен уменьшатся (троеточие в конце). Но получается, что красный лэйбл будет всегда настолько большим, насколько ему нужно, чтобы текст в нем не уменьшался, а текст в синим лэйбле уменьшается. Я поставил приоритет у констейнта redLabel.leading >=1 blueLabel.trailing == 750, и это должно было по идее решить проблему, однако этот констрейнт в таком случае вообще игнорируется и получается как на скрине ниже:

[image]

В идеале должно выглядеть вот так:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось так:

-blue label: Leading Space to SuperView постоянный; Trailing Space to SuperView's center <= 0

-red label: Leading Space to Blue Label >= 7 (минимальный оступ между двумя лэйблами) ; Trailing Space to Date Label постоянный.

Приоритет вообще не пришлось трогать - везде 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Вам необходимо использовать aspect ratio constrant для ширины blueLabel c соотношением сторон 2 : 1 и постоянной, равной вашему отступу от левого края для blueLabel. Удачи.

[image: Для blueLabel]

[image: для redLabel]

Comment: Тогда redLabel будет всегда одного размера, а идея в том, что если например в blueLabel мало текста, то красный должен растянуться до края синего и в красный влезет больше текста. Но если в синем много текста, то максимум, он должен растянуться на пол экрана.